# Formatting datetime in python

Tags: python, string, datetime, formatting

```
print str(now.month) + str(now.day) + str(now.year)
```

Result: **1162014**

How do I further format the result to add slashes: **11/6/2014**

Also how would I do formatting for hour, minute, and second? **hh:mm:ss**

**Displaying datetime as month/day/year & hours:minutes:seconds:**

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print datetime.datetime.strftime(now, '%m/%d/%Y')
print datetime.datetime.strftime(now, '%H:%M:%S')
```

**Displaying datetime as month/day/year & hours:minutes:seconds on one line:**

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print datetime.datetime.strftime(now, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

*special thanks to senshin for the help*

Comment: Make sure you check the case on your statement for printing the time - lowercase `%m` means "month", while uppercase `%M` means "minute".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `datetime.strftime()`. I assume you meant `1/16/2014`, rather than `11/6/2014`, given that today is the 16th of January.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(now, '%m/%d/%Y')
'01/16/2014'
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(now, '%H:%M:%S')
'14:18:16'
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(now, '%I:%M:%S')
'02:18:16'
```

If for some reason you didn't want to use `datetime.strftime()`, you could instead do:

```
>>> print '/'.join(map(str, [now.month, now.day, now.year]))
'1/16/2014'
```

Comment: @user3201139 No, you should also use `datetime.strftime` for formatting the time part of it! `datetime.datetime.strftime(now, '%H:%M:%S')`. Or, if you want twelve-hour time, use `%I:%M:%S` instead.

Comment: Thank you, ill give it a try right now. Whats the benefit of the first format versus the second format?

Comment: @user3201139 Maintainability, I guess. It's more concise to use `datetime.strftime`, and that's also considered the standard way of formatting dates in Python. It also gives you more flexibility if you want to change the time format later on.

Comment: How would I display them on the same line in the form: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: @user3201139 You should read the [`strftime` and `strptime` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). For that format, you just put the date and time specifications together. `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S`.

Comment: thank you, I have edited the OP with the updated info to make the post more valuable to the stackOF community, thx again!